# display posts by month/year ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Not sure where to start with this so here goes.. I am building a small blog in which the date of each  post is displayed, overtime there will be many blog posts per month, for which i would like to group together by the month it was published.

I want to display it like this in the view

```
Archives

January 2013
February 2013
March 2013
etc
```

When i click on a given month the idea is it will take me to all the posts that where published within that month.

So far I can group all the posts by month and year

```
@posts_by_month = Post.all.group_by { |post| post.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }
```

In my view i then render like so

```
<% @posts_by_month.each do |m| %>
  <%= m %>
<% end %>
```

Which returns this in the view

```
["July 2013", [#<Post id: 1, title: "Ruby News", comments: "dsfdsfdsfdsfdsfds", category_id: 1, user_id: 1, created_at: "2013-07-26 07:10:25", updated_at: "2013-07-26 07:19:27", photo_file_name: "pf-7.jpg", photo_content_type: "image/jpeg", photo_file_size: 162495, photo_updated_at: "2013-07-26 07:19:26">]]
```

So at the moment i have a hash where the month/year is the key and then all my posts in an array, is that correct?

All i want to display is the Month/Year and then click that month to be taken to all the posts for that month

Any help appreciated

EDIT

ok silly me, forgot my basics on key/value pairing, i have got just the date to display

```
<% @posts_by_month.each do |m,p| %>
  <%= link_to m %>
<% end %>
```

Now i just need to be able to click the link to see all posts for that month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
= link_to m, posts_path(:month => m)
```

Now in `posts#index`, fetch the posts based on `params[:month]`

```
if params[:month]
  date = Date.parse("1 #{params[:month]}")  # to get the first day of the month
  @posts = Post.where(:created_at => date..date.end_of_month)  # get posts for the month
else
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, helps a lot..i have another question though, so the url is now posts?month=July+2013 for example, how do i ensure that just the posts for that month are in the view?.....oh hang on think i have it

Comment: ah no my way didnt work @archives = Post.find(params[:month])

Comment: thats a really nice way of doing it, thanks very much and ive learned something new here aswell

Comment: @Richlewis, glad to be of help. :)

Comment: havent seen this syntax before date..date.end_of_month, i can see that the first date is a variable that has been created where it is parsing , but its the .. thats throwing me? could you explain please, thanks

Comment: `..` is for creating a [Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html). eg: for nums 1 to 10, u can use `1..10`. In the answer the condition is `created_at` should be in the date range first day of month to last day of the month