# Rails - Displaying links to month's posts by created_at month and year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

like the titles says - I'm trying to create links that will take a user to a page, showing all blog posts made that month.

On the archive index page I would like them shown as such:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: circle;
  }

li {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<h3>2016</h3>
<ul>
  <li>October</li>
  <li>September</li>
  <li>Etc.</li>
</ul>
<h3>2015</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Same deal here</li>
</ul>
```

I used the reply to a post found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010721/display-posts-by-month-year-ruby) to get it to show correctly on the index page (just by months for now). However, when I click on the link to a certain month - it shows all of the posts. The url is reading as :http://localhost:3000/posts?month=July+2016 for the July section - but all posts are showing.

Here are my snippets - I did alter them a little to fit my needs from the answer linked above.

Index:

```
<% @posts_by_month.each do |m, p| %>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <ul>
            <li><%= link_to m, posts_path(:month => m) %></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">

    </div>
<% end %>
```

archive_controller:

```
def index
    @posts_by_month = Post.all.order(created_at: :desc).group_by { |post| post.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }

    if params[:month && :year]
        date = Date.parse("1 #{params[:month]}")
        @arch_posts = Post.where(publish: true).where(:created_at => date..date.end_of_month).order(created_at: :desc)
    else
        @arch_posts = Post.all
    end
end
```

I wasn't sure if I should have put that in the post_controller or not. I tried to shuffle things around, but nothings been working. Here's my post_controller index in case:

```
  def index
    if params[:search].present?
        @posts = Post.matching_title_or_content(params[:search]).page params[:page]
    else
        @posts = Post.all.order(id: :desc).page params[:page]
    end

    @notif_count = Notification.where(notifiable_type: 'Visitor').count + Notification.where(notifiable_type: 'Comment').count
    @mess_count = Message.where(status: false).count
    @to_approve_count = Comment.where(status: false).count
  end
```

I'm new to Ruby so any input is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need `@posts_by_month` to return posts of the month or `@arch_posts`

Comment: @posts_by_month I think. I kinda pieced together a few different things trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This wont be proper solution since I dont know your view code but still I will mention a few things I noticed in your code.

1. `if params[:month && :year]`. I dont think this is a correct syntax. It should be like `if params[:month] && params[:year]`
2. You are not sending any `year` params, as you can see you have only `?month=July+2016` in URL so this will send only params which has value of `July 2016` here `+` represents a blank space not different parameter. Maybe you want something like `?month=July&year=2016`.
3. `Date.parse("1 #{params[:month]}")` maybe it's correct but I am suspicious about what you are try to achieve by keeping a `1` inside the string.

Comment: Thanks. I kinda put this together from a few different examples I found after the each didn't work. I spent about 4 hours trying different things, so I was really just grasping.